# how to turn on/off console/terminal window when running one exe file

Tags: python, debugging, console, subprocess, pyinstaller

I have mainwindow.py and complied to one exe file. mainwindow.exe

When I double-click and run the mainwindow.exe, the console is popping up , but the mainwindow never appears. And the console keeps looping print messages with:

> *debug mode is : True   ######### launch cosole start*

Also I can see there are many  '_MEIXXX' files created in temp folder.

Here is a part of my code.

```
## I am mainly using pySide6 to build mainwindow. 
## After that these code call it to launch the application. 
## If I remove debug module/block, everything is working correctly!

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_rsc =  Resource_path()

    cssPath = my_rsc.resourcePath('style01.css')#.replace('\\', '/')
    with open(cssPath, 'r') as f:
        style = f.read()
        #print(style)
    app.setStyleSheet(style)
    print('setStylesheet is done')
    
    iconPath = my_rsc.resourcePath('image_icons\headShot_small.png')
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(iconPath))
```

and important code is here;

```
    debug_mode=True
    print(f'debug mode is : {debug_mode}   ######### launch cosole start')
    if debug_mode: ## after this, code is not working properly ##
        import subprocess
        subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m','console'])
        print('console is open for debug') 
    else:
        print('no debug mode')**

    ## this lastly call mainwindow class and launch application
    wd = MainWindow()
    wd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I tried to insert the above debug blocks in **class mainwindow():** , instead of **if **name** == '**main**':** block . However, it's the same problem.

I know I could modify with/without console when using pyinstaller. but ideally I want to add a debug ON/OFF check-box in UI window. So if user can choose debug mode or not, it would be great.

Comment: What is it you think the code in the bottom section is supposed to be doing? Also, clearly that isn't you actual code or your terminal wouldn't say `debug mode is : True`  it would say `False` instead

Comment: you are right, and rewrite to 'debug_mode=True'. Anyway, I guess the idea of my code is probably wrong, and I just wanted to do my best before asking question directly. 

What I want is, when it sets to 'debug_mode=True' and launch the exe file, the terminal/console window is up. Then a user can see print message to do debug.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot turn the console on or off after it's already been compiled